# C++ Integer to pointer conversion

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers

So recently I've been dealing with WinAPI's [`WriteProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`ReadProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which both take `LPVOID` as their second argument which is the actual address in the memory of another process we want to read from.

Considering that, would this integer to pointer conversion be correct C++ code (without undefined behavior, etc.):

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    WriteProcessMemory(/*...*/,
        //want to read from memory address 0x1234 in the target process
        reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<uintptr_t>(0x1234)),
        /*...*/);

    return 0;
}
```

AFAIK, the standard says that `uintptr_t` is an integer type which is able to hold a pointer without the value of the pointer being changed. Since it is an integer, I should be able to store 0x1234 in it. The standard also says that `reinterpret_cast`ing an `uintptr_t` to a `void*` will also leave the value unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows platforms the pointer is stored exactly in the same way as the same bit-count integer type. The difference is how the compiler interpretes the value of a pointer and an int. So no conversion is neccessary.

Casting it to `void *`/`LPVOID` is just to make the compiler happy and accept the integer value in a place for pointer and no conversion is made. Going through static_cast+reinterpret_cast is overkill in this case.

As long as you are sure that the correct address is 0x1234, conversion is not needed. Just a plain `(LPVOID)0x1234` or `(void *)0x1234` should do.

[edit] As noted in the comments the constant may get truncated. Then no conversion can fix the pointer value. A way to handle this is to explicitly specify the type used in the constant:

E.g. `(void *)0x1234567812345678ULL` will be OK because the compiler is instructed to use 64bit unsigned type.

Comment: And if we were to disregard that I'm using WinAPI or Windows in general, would `reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<uintptr_t>(0x1234))` still be the correct and standard way to convert an integer to a `void*`?

Comment: It depends on how you have got the pointer value. If you have a pointer and do `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(static_cast<void *>(p))` and then print the value - then yes.

Comment: And if I have an integer `i` and do `reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<uintptr_t>(i))`?

Comment: @MooingDuck What do you mean? uintptr_t is the type that have the same number of bits as the pointers both on 32 and 64 bit platforms.

Comment: @bbonev: That is true, but `0x1234` doesn't.  And you wrote "`(void *)0x1234` should do.", but I'm not immediately certain it covers all cases, _because_ of the of the lengthening.

Comment: @Tuntuni this depends on bit count of `i`, if it have enough bits to hold a pointer value then it should work. But if for example you have a 32bit integer type it obviously will not be able to containt a pointer value on a 64bit system.

Comment: @MooingDuck I've got what you mean, you are right - 0x1234 is OK like it is (and will always be - its constant), but 0x1234567812345678ULL needs ULL (or the proper suffix that the MS compiler uses for 64bit constants). BTW if the constant gets truncated no complex cast can recover it back.

Comment: I'm curious about what happens for `(void*)0x80000000` though.  I'm not 100% certain it does the right thing.

Comment: @bbonev: Actually, I think `0x1234567812345678` automatically extends, avoiding the problem.  Also `(void *)0x80000000ULL` avoids the problem.

Comment: MS states ULL or i64 suffix is the way to end 64bit constant. By default the constants are signed integer.

Comment: Well, I guess that answers my questions. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @bbonev: Sortof, `ULL` or `i64` suffixes are ways to make literals into 64bit _that otherwise wouldn't be_.  By default, literals are signed integer, _unless a signed integer cannot hold that value_ in which case it becomes a `signed long long`, and if _that_ cannot hold the value, it becomes a `unsigned long long`.  So `0x1234567812345678` is a 64 bit value, but `0x80000000` is not